# Two sidebars issue

Tags: html, css

I have problem with sidebars on my website. I have two sidebars both 250px, one is on the left side and the second on the right side and have between div with content. That left sidebar is ok but that second doesnt want to change place for the right side and is on the left on place that first.

```css
.info {
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-main {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 56px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-container">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <div class="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <h2 class="getname">Tommy Hilfiger</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="active">
      <p class="menu">Activity</p>
    </div>
    <div class="followers">
      <p class="menu">Followers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="friends">
      <p class="menu">Friends</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photos">
      <p class="menu">Photos</p>
    </div>
    <div class="edit">
      <p class="menu">Edit</p>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <ul class="info">
    <div class="aqt">
    </div>
  </ul>
  <div class="content-main">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `<ul>` with `<div>`, you should use `<ul><li>...</li></ul>` otherwise change `<ul>` to `<div>` `(<ul> is unordered list, <li> is list item).`

Secondly, the way you're building the html, you're not splitting `<div>` elements (division), you're actually building one block with two lists and a division.

if you want to have **[SideBar][Content][secondBar]** use this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftbar">
    anything
  </div>
  <div class="content">

  </div>
  <div class="rightbar">

  </div>
</div>
```

Use the following css as fundamental, style after:

```
div.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "leftbar content rightbar";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
div.leftbar{
  grid-area: leftbar;
}
div.content{
  grid-area: content;
}
div.rightbar{
  grid-area: rightbar;
}
```